# Are Symfony parameters still read from parameters.yml after run cache:warmup?

Tags: php, symfony

I cannot find any doc that describes what the framework does with parameters after a `cache:warmup`.

- Are they still read from `parameters.yml`?
- Are they stored somewhere in the cache?
- Is there any difference between a development and a production environment (`debug=true|false` I mean)?

I'm using Symfony 3.4, in case the answer changes with the version.

Comment: The best 'documentation' is the generated files under var/cache.  They can be a bit overwhelming at first glance but understanding how they work can solve many mysterious configuration issues.  And you can see the differences between the various environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony has a "compiled" service container.

Compilation occurs during cache warmup, so values in `parameters.yml` or any other file like that will only be read during compilation, and if changed you'd need to regenerate the cache (`cache:clear`).

During development, usually Symfony will recompile the container when needed. However, it's not 100% reliable, and occasionally you'll need to clear cache manually (which can be as simple as calling `rm -rf /var/cache/*`, since if the container is not compiled Symfony will then compile it again).